# Find availble disk space in unix without parsing `df` output

Tags: unix, shell, df

When I type `df -k .`, I get the following output

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       16512936 8650196   7023932  56% /
```

What I do is tail the last line and extract fourth field to get it correctly.

But if file system name is long, say e.g. `/dev/niraj-asdsdsd-dsdsdsa`, then `df` prints further details on a new line and using my logic I get **56%** instead of **7023932**.

So my question is, how to determine the exact free space in any situation?

Comment: "But if file system name is long, say e.g. `/dev/niraj-asdsdsd-dsdsdsa`, then `df` prints further details on a new line and using my logic I get 56% instead of 7023932." -- In case you want to stick to `df`, [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1599668/432690) is how you properly do it with `df`.

Answer (score 4):

The `stat`utility, which is handy for getting file statistics, can also give you informations about file systems, just supply the `-f` option.

But be sure that you supply the mount point (e.g. `/boot`) and not the device file (`/dev/sda1`)! Because in the latter case `stat` will report statistics of the `/dev` file system, which is (on debian) a virtual filesystem and has nothing to do with the physical disc:

```
$ mount | grep sda1
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext2 (rw,relatime,errors=continue,user_xattr,acl)
$ env stat -f /dev/sda2
 File: "/dev/sda1"
    ID: 0        Namelen: 255     Type: tmpfs
Block size: 4096       Fundamental block size: 4096
Blocks: Total: 2560       Free: 2560       Available: 2560
Inodes: Total: 497355     Free: 496852
$ env stat -f /boot
  File: "/boot"
    ID: fe082d7c0c42ea6f Namelen: 255     Type: ext2/ext3
Block size: 1024       Fundamental block size: 1024
Blocks: Total: 99150      Free: 52490      Available: 47370
Inodes: Total: 25688      Free: 25355
```

- The difference between the *Free* and *Available* count results from the reserved blocks for *root*.
- I used `env` to make sure that not the builtin stat command of your shell (which might or might not provide all the used options) is used.

So, to answer your question, you can use a customized (`-c`) stat output format to get the avalable space (`%a`) on `/`:

```
$ env stat -f -c %a /
1711744
```

This is in blocks, so be clever and let the system do a multiplication with the block size in KB units (`%S/1024`) by piping the output into the `bc` calculator:

```
$ env stat -f -c '%a*%S/1024' / | bc
6846976
```

Let's check with `df`:

```
$ df /
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       25066604 16939628   6846976  72% /
```

Fine, same number reported!

Answer (score 2):

Thank you so much, I was having problems with df since depending on the system it gets the 3rd or 4th column, this way I solved it!
I was developing a bash script to check the available space on /, /boot and /var on various systems and send a report if less than a certain amount of MB.

I've converted it to MB since I find it more easily readable just adding another division

```
echo $(env stat -f -c '%a*%S/1024/1024' /boot | bc)MB free on /boot
```

Answer (score 0):

Niraj - Have you looked at the di utility?  This might offer at least an easier way to extract the data you need, it offers a CSV format output of the drive space.

```
di -c
```

Answer (score 0):

To show the available disk space in Kb or Mb, you can use the following command:

```
export LC_NUMERIC="en_ZA.utf8" && free_disk_space_before=$(env stat -f -c '%a*%S/1024' / | bc) && echo "Free Disk Space:" $(/usr/bin/printf "%'3.3f" ${free_disk_space_before}) "Kb"

export LC_NUMERIC="en_ZA.utf8" && free_disk_space_before=$(env stat -f -c '%a*%S/1024/1024' / | bc) && echo "Free Disk Space:" $(/usr/bin/printf "%'d" ${free_disk_space_before}) "Mb"
```

The results are as follows:

```
Free Disk Space: 874,064 Kb
Free Disk Space: 874 Mb
```

The conversion to en_ZA.utf8 is just one way to get the comma between the thousands.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).