# Not the same output format from `df` in different Linux distributions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, df

In Ubuntu the output of this command

```
df --exclude={tmpfs,devtmpfs,squashfs,overlay} | sed -e /^Filesystem/d | awk '{print $6 " " $1 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5}'
```

is:

```
/ /dev/mapper/dockerVG-rootLV 8110496 40591632 17%
/dockerssd /dev/mapper/ssdVG-ssdLV 214133656 274642488 44%
/dockerhdd /dev/mapper/hddVG-hddLV 83278236 1385191240 6%
/var/lib/docker /dev/mapper/hddVG-dockerLV 76046204 412729940 16%
```

That is what I need.

On CentOS 6 I get this output:

```
 /dev/mapper/vg_rproxy-lv_root
 51475068 43192316 12% /
/boot /dev/sda1 82688 379364 18%
 /dev/mapper/vg_rproxy-lv_home
 77349888 73119692 1% /home
```

It's a mess.

Full output from the CentOS 6:

```
$ df
Filesystem           1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_rproxy-lv_root
                      51475068 5661336  43192292  12% /
tmpfs                   957140       0    957140   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1               487652   82688    379364  18% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_rproxy-lv_home
                      77349888  294352  73119692   1% /home
```

What is the problem? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### tl;dr

Use `df -P`.

---

#### Full answer

`/dev/mapper/vg_rproxy-lv_root` and `/dev/mapper/vg_rproxy-lv_home` are relatively long strings. It appears `df` in CentOS *decides* to split their entries to two lines, this breaks the logic when you want to parse the output further.

In narrow terminals this may be a good thing, creating semi-columnized human-readable output even despite limited horizontal space. I would prefer this not to happen when `df` writes to a non-tty (a pipe in your case).

*Maybe* `df` in Ubuntu behaves similarly if entries in the `Filesystem` column are long; maybe you just didn't experience this because yours are relatively short. I don't know, this is not important. What is important is `df` is a POSIX tool and should follow [the specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/df.html). But the specification explicitly states:

> Historical `df` implementations vary considerably in their default output. It was therefore necessary to describe the default output in a loose manner to accommodate all known historical implementations and to add a portable option (`-P`) to provide information in a portable format.

About the option:

> `-P`
> Produce output in the format described in the STDOUT section.

And finally the relevant part of the STDOUT section (emphasis mine):

> The implementation may adjust the spacing of the header line and the individual data lines so that the information is presented in orderly columns.
>
> The remaining output **with `-P`** shall consist of **one line of information for each specified file system**. These lines shall be formatted as follows:
>
> ```
> "%s %d %d %d %d%% %s\n", <file system name>, <total space>,
>     <space used>, <space free>, <percentage used>,
>     <file system root>
> ```

So `df` is allowed to output anything, unless you use `-P`. Without `-P` some implementations of `df` may produce predictable and parsable output, others… not so much. Their behavior may or may not be documented well enough. Therefore in general, when parsing the output of `df` you should always use `-P`.

Just adding `-P` will probably be enough to fix your specific problem.

Note `-P` governs the format only. Overall POSIX specification applies only in the POSIX locale. Additionally modern implementations of `df` tend to use 1024-byte blocks by default, while POSIX states the default is 512. In my Debian 10 `df` from GNU coreutils falls back to the POSIX default when `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is set in the environment. Portably you can force 1024-byte blocks with `-k`.

This is a portable command that produces (almost) parsable output:

```
LC_ALL=POSIX df -Pk
```

Almost parsable, because entries in the `Filesystem` column may contain spaces, I think; although in a sanely configured OS they don't.

You may omit `LC_ALL=POSIX` and still get expected results, but in general it should be there for parsing. E.g. in my Polish locale your `sed -e /^Filesystem/d` doesn't do its job because I get a Polish term for "filesystem" from my `df`. `LC_ALL=POSIX` fixes this. Still my *personal* preference is not to rely on anything in the header. I would use `sed 1d` or `tail -n +2`; or delegate the task to `awk`, since `awk` is already in your pipeline. This would be:

```
LC_ALL=POSIX df -Pk --exclude={tmpfs,devtmpfs,squashfs,overlay} \
| awk 'NR>1 {print $6 " " $1 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5}'
```

Finally `--exclude=` is not a portable option. Apparently it works for you in both systems in question, it may not work in other systems though.

Comment: Or use `findmnt --df --json` to leverage a widely supported parsable format instead.