# Not the same output of small bash-script on different Linux systems

Tags: linux, bash, partitioning, sed, awk

I have a small script, that makes `JOIN` of `LSBLK` and `DF` commands.
Script:

```
lsblk -n -b --output KNAME,NAME,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT | egrep -v "fd0|ram|loop|sr0|hdc|cdrom|[SWAP]" |
while read kname name size mountpoint ; do
    printf '%-5s' "$kname"
    printf '%-20s' "$name"
    printf '%30d' "$size"
    printf '%-10s' " "
    if [ "$mountpoint" != "" ] ; then
         df -P --exclude={tmpfs,devtmpfs,squashfs,overlay} | sed -e /^Filesystem/d | awk '{print $6 " " $1 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5}' | grep "$mountpoint "
    else
        echo
    fi
done
```

On `Ubuntu` I have output:

```
sda  sda                                    53687091200
sda1 └─sda1                             53684994048
dm-3 └─dockerVG-rootLV                   53682896896          / /dev/mapper/dockerVG-rootLV 11332388 37369740 24%
sdb  sdb                                  2147483648000
sdb1 └─sdb1                           2147482599424
dm-1 ├─hddVG-dockerLV                  536866717696          /var/lib/docker /dev/mapper/hddVG-dockerLV 47321992 441454152 10%
dm-2 └─hddVG-hddLV                    1610612736000          /dockerhdd /dev/mapper/hddVG-hddLV 99436560 1369032916 7%
sdc  sdc                                   751619276800
sdc1 └─sdc1                            751618228224
dm-0 └─ssdVG-ssdLV                     214744170496          /dockerssd /dev/mapper/ssdVG-ssdLV 66987204 127882232 35%
```

It is, that I wanted. But on `CentOS 6`:

```
sda  sda                                   136365211648
sda1 ├─sda1                               524288000          /boot /dev/sda1 82688 379364 18%
sda2 └─sda2                            135839875072
dm-0 ├─vg_rproxy-lv_root-bash: printf: (dm-0): invalid number
                             0          dm-2 └─vg_rproxy-lv_home-bash: printf: (dm-2): invalid number
```

Output of `LSBLK` on this `CentOS 6`:

```
sda   sda                          136365211648
sda1  ├─sda1                          524288000 /boot
sda2  └─sda2                       135839875072
dm-0    ├─vg_rproxy-lv_root (dm-0)  53687091200 /
dm-2    └─vg_rproxy-lv_home (dm-2)  80606134272 /home
```

Output of `DF` on this `CentOS 6`:

```
/ /dev/mapper/vg_rproxy-lv_root 5778636 43074992 12%
/boot /dev/sda1 82688 379364 18%
/home /dev/mapper/vg_rproxy-lv_home 294352 73119692 1%
```

Why my script is not working on `CentOS 6` ? Could You help me ?
If You have example, how to resolve this via `AWK`, it would be great.

Comment: The culprit is the space in `vg_rproxy-lv_root (dm-0)` and such.

Comment: Have you seen [this comment](https://superuser.com/q/1599648/432690#comment2438400_1599668)? Can you use `findmnt --tree --df --json`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes, it is enough for me. Thanks.
Your command will not work on old `CentOS 6`

Comment: Also, be aware that bash is always going through changes and getting better.  When I was writing installers using bash, RedHat (CentOS) always had an older version than the other distros and many of the things I had working on SUSE and Ubuntu didn't work without modifying them for CentOS.